# GitHub has changes in my branch that I didn't do

Tags: git, github

I'm new using Git and I found this behavior not coherent to what I was told. There is a branch x from which I checked out to a new branch y so both should have the same.

```
 git checkout -b y
```

I made some changes in my branch and other people made changes in the x branch. After I coded all I needed I made a commit in my branch

```
 git commit
```

then I checked out to branch x

```
 git checkout x
```

to update my local remote with

```
 git pull
```

then I checkout back to my branch

```
 git checkout y
```

and then being in branch y I pulled from branch x to have all changes from x hosted on GitHub merged into my local branch y

```
 git pull origin x
```

then I pushed to the remote to ruin everything not on purpose

```
 git push
```

I didn't have any conflicts so I went to GitHub and made a compare between x and y, and to my surprise, there were changes I didn't do (all my changes were there too though). Is this normal, what could have happened?

Comment: `pull` is a `git fetch` followed by an automatic `git merge`.  Are the extra changes stuff from upstream's `x` branch?

Comment: As far as I understand the compare in GitHub between x and y uses the upstreamed branches (everything that is in the repo online), so based on that, yes the extra changes are in the upstream's x branch

Answer (score 2):

> "and other people made changes in the x branch"

followed by

> git pull origin x

(which boils down to a merge with x as source)

explains why you now see that

> there were changes I didn't do

These are the changes brought by branch `x`

Comment: @RomainValeri Yes but as I brought those changes to y, I should have y as a copy of x, plus my changes. After uploading my branch, when I compare the online versions of x and y, shouldn't the comparison mark only my changes (as my branch uploaded has the x's changes already)?

Comment: @user33276346 I also wanted to ask : what did you expect `git pull origin x` to do, what was it supposed to achieve?

Comment: @user33276346 Oh! OK it's clearer... you're not at all confused about the effect of pull/merge, this is about reading github's interface more than anything else I guess. (which I'm not familiar with, I'm mostly on bitbucket...)

Comment: `git pull origin x` was used to bring all the changes in x and merge them into my branch.